# What does %>% mean in R programming language?

Tags: r

I was reviewing some public code and came across an expression that I'm not familiar with at all:

```
clv <- orders %>%
  group_by(clientId) %>%
  summarise(clv=sum(grossmarg))
```

What does `%>%` mean?

Thank you.

Comment: This will get you started: http://www.r-statistics.com/2014/08/simpler-r-coding-with-pipes-the-present-and-future-of-the-magrittr-package/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27125672/what-does-function-mean-in-r