# How can I convert Json to data frame in R

Tags: r, json, rjson

I'd like to convert my json data to data frame in R. Here is what I've done so far:

```
library("rjson")
result <- fromJSON(file ="mypath/data.json")
json_data_frame <- as.data.frame(result)
```

However, it comes to an error like this:

> Error in data.frame(company_id = "12345678", country_name = "China",
> :    arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 2, 0

I also tried the following code:

```
library("rjson")
result <- fromJSON(file ="mypath/data.json")
final_data <- do.call(rbind, result)
```

And this error comes up:

> Warning message: In (function (..., deparse.level = 1)  :   number of
> columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 3)

I don't know what is going on here and how can I solve it. I will appreciate if I could get some help on this.

Here are some pieces of my json data:

```
{"business_id": "1234567", "Country_name": "China", "hours": {"Monday": {"close": "02:00", "open": "11:00"}, "Tuesday": {"close": "02:00", "open": "11:00"}, "Friday": {"close": "02:00", "open": "11:00"}, "Wednesday": {"close": "02:00", "open": "11:00"}, "Thursday": {"close": "02:00", "open": "11:00"}, "Sunday": {"close": "02:00", "open": "12:00"}, "Saturday": {"close": "02:00", "open": "12:00"}}, "open": true, "categories": ["Bars", "Nightlife", "Restaurants"], "city": "Beijing", "review_count": 5, "name": "Chen's Bar", "neighborhoods": ["West End"], "attributes": {"Take-out": true, "Wi-Fi": "free", "Good For": {"dessert": false, "latenight": false, "lunch": false, "dinner": false, "breakfast": false, "brunch": false}, "Good For Dancing": false, "Noise Level": "loud", "Takes Reservations": false, "Delivery": false, "Ambience": {"romantic": false, "intimate": false, "classy": false, "hipster": false, "divey": false, "touristy": false, "trendy": false, "upscale": false, "casual": false}, "Happy Hour": true, "Parking": {"garage": false, "street": false, "validated": false, "lot": false, "valet": false}, "Has TV": true, "Outdoor Seating": false, "Attire": "casual", "Alcohol": "full_bar", "Waiter Service": true, "Accepts Credit Cards": true, "Good for Kids": false, "Good For Groups": true, "Caters": true, "Price Range": 1}, "type": "business"}
```

Comment: Not every JSON can be converted into a `data.frame`, since they are way more general. JSONs map very well to `R` `list`s; that's why `fromJSON` returns a list. If you can convert to a `data.frame`, it really depends on the structure of your object. Share an example of your JSON and state what would look like your desired output.

Comment: Can you paste some of the data contained in your JSON?

Comment: Thank you for answering @nicola and @enlego. I have updated some of my data here. It is a little bit complicated. Would you suggest me analyse it with `list` directly? Or try to convert it to data frame?(But at least I know where the problem is :) thanks)

Comment: that data looks like two sources blended together. However, if you want to try to figure out how to unpack it manually, I would suggest using something like a json to table viewer. (you can save the json to a .txt file then copy & paste. Try this: http://www.jsontableviewer.com/# Then you can figure out how to use `[[1]]$...` and so on to unpack one nested list at a time

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try using jsonlite library. It work for me

```
fromJSON(temp) %>% as.data.frame
```

Following is output
  [image]

if you want list.

```
fromJSON(temp)
```

Comment: From what package do you use " %>%"? I have tried with dplyr and it doesn't work for me. Does it work for any json? Thank you

Comment: I use it from dplyr, check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27125672/what-does-function-mean-in-r, or you can just do `as.data.frame(fromJSON(temp))`

Comment: `%>%` is from `library(magrittr)`

Answer (score 7):

Load the jsonlite package

```
library(jsonlite)
```

wine_json is a JSON

```
wine_json <- '{"name":"Chateau Migraine", "year":1997, "alcohol_pct":12.4, "color":"red", "awarded":false}'
```

Convert wine_json into a list:

```
wine <- fromJSON(wine_json)
```

Print structure of wine

```
str(wine)
```