# Parse R Character Vector into DataFrame

Tags: r, shiny

I'm been working with JSON response from API, and have been able to return the data in a format that looks very JSON (which is good) and not struggling to get into DataFrame.  Here is the code:

```
message(typeof((results_response)))
# character
message(length((results_response)))
# 1 

message(results_response)
# {"central_time":{"0":"2020-04-06 15:47:00","1":"2020-04-06 15:47:15"},"Va_V":{"0":286.032,"1":286.207}}
```

The goal would not hard coding the keys, because there could be other responses when different keys.  thank you!

Comment: @akrun yes.  When i do that is causing this:  `0` = "2020-04-09 15:47:00", `1` = "2020-04-09 15:47:15")list(`0` = 286.032 `1` = 286.207)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this helps

```
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
fromJSON(results_response) %>%
     transpose %>% 
     bind_rows
 # A tibble: 2 x 2
 #  central_time         Va_V
 #* <chr>               <dbl>
#1 2020-04-06 15:47:00  286.
#2 2020-04-06 15:47:15  286.
```

#### data

```
results_response <- "{\"central_time\":{\"0\":\"2020-04-06 15:47:00\",\"1\":\"2020-04-06 15:47:15\"},\"Va_V\":{\"0\":286.032,\"1\":286.207}}"
```

Comment: Ran the code, got this:  Warning: Error in : Argument 10 is a list, must contain atomic vectors

Comment: @jKraut i couldn't reproduce the warning/error.  May be some package version difference issue

Comment: I think it's additional fields in the JSON response coming through causing the issue.

Comment: @jKraut ok, I run this based on the example as I showed in the post

Comment: In another field it had a "."  in the key name.  I removed that and your code worked perfectly.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following should work

```
library(jsonlite)

# Your JSON charachter vector.
json <- 

df <- as.data.frame(fromJSON(json))
```

See [jsonlite Documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/vignettes/json-aaquickstart.html) and the answer to [How can I convert Json to data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454638/how-can-i-convert-json-to-data-frame-in-r).

I hope this helps!

**EDITED**
The following code did run without errors.

```
library(jsonlite)

json <- as.character(
  '{"central_time":{"0":"2020-04-06 15:47:00","1":"2020-04-06 15:47:15"}, "Va_V":{"0":286.032, "1":286.207}}')

as.data.frame(fromJSON(json))
```

Can it be that you have a duplicate key?

I also tried the following (this should be equivalent to the correct answer).

```
library(jsonlite)

json <- as.character(
  '{"central_time":{"0":"2020-04-06 15:47:00","1":"2020-04-06 15:47:15"}, "Va_V":{"0":286.032, "1":286.207}}')

from.json <- fromJSON(json)
from.json <- t(from.json)
df <- do.call(cbind, from.json)
```

I know that you have already marked the correct answer, but can you please try the code nevertheless? I'm just curious what went wrong.

Comment: Ran the code, got this:  Warning: Error in <Anonymous>: arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

Comment: That is weired. Because I don't. Please see the edited answer.