# R - Trying to parse a json and convert in to to a data frame

Tags: r, json, dataframe

I'm trying but not able to understand how to convert the below json:

```
["{\"tables\":[{\"name\":\"PrimaryResult\",\"columns\":[{\"name\":\"timestamp\",\"type\":\"datetime\"},{\"name\":\"count_\",\"type\":\"long\"}],\"rows\":[[\"2020-10-26T00:00:00Z\",13937],[\"2020-10-25T00:00:00Z\",94029]]}]}"]
```

into a data frame like this one:

[image]

Comment: Have you searched within stackoverflow? See this link. It might work for you by using jsonlite package: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454638/how-can-i-convert-json-to-data-frame-in-r

Comment: Have you checked your `json` string. It shows invalid data when parsed on `firefox`. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Using `jsonlite::fromJSON`.

```
json <- "{\"tables\":[{\"name\":\"PrimaryResult\",\"columns\":[{\"name\":\"timestamp\",\"type\":\"datetime\"},{\"name\":\"count_\",\"type\":\"long\"}],\"rows\":[[\"2020-10-26T00:00:00Z\",13937],[\"2020-10-25T00:00:00Z\",94029]]}]}"
dat <- jsonlite::fromJSON(json)
res <- setNames(as.data.frame(dat$tables$rows[[1]]), unlist(dat$tables$columns[[1]][1, ]))
res
#              timestamp datetime
# 1 2020-10-26T00:00:00Z    13937
# 2 2020-10-25T00:00:00Z    94029
```