# Converting JSON file to df in R

Tags: r, json

I have never worked with json files before so sorry in advance if my language/explanation is difficult to understand. First time posting so big apologies if this is in the wrong format too!

I'm trying to convert a json file in R, so far I can upload the file into a list using:

```
jdata <- RJSONIO::fromJSON("./data.json")
```

The original raw file looks like:

```
[
    {
        "name": "11 bit studios",
        "website": "https://11bitstudios.com/",
        "headquarters": "Warsaw, ",
        "industry": [
            "Software",
            "Gaming"
        ],
        "side": "",
        "actions": {
            "support": [{
                "country": "",
                "measures": [
                    "All profits from \"This War of Mine\" for seven days after announcement went go to special fund which was donated to Ukrainian Red Cross. In summary, $850,000 were raised"
                ]
            }]
        },
        "links": [
            "https://twitter.com/11bitstudios/status/1496904408344449027",
            "https://twitter.com/11bitstudios/status/1499736525357129730"
        ]
```

And the list looks like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhSyA.png)

What I'm trying to do is get a df that has the following headings:

```
$name $website $headquarters $industry $actions $country $measures
```

I hope that makes sense!

--edit for example--
See picture:
[example df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y81iQ.png)

Comment: Maybe [this quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454638/how-can-i-convert-json-to-data-frame-in-r) is helping you?

Comment: Or [this](https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-read-json-files-in-r) post?

Comment: As seen in your example, there can be multiple industries, and 'actions' is a complete multidimensional list. A data frame only supports a single value per cell. Can you give an example of how you'd like the data frame to look for the example entry?

Comment: just added an edit with an example of the df! Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON allows each company to have multiple industries, multiple actions, multiple countries they support, and multiple measures to take. However, given your example desired result, **we** will only get the first of each per company.

```r
jdata <- RJSONIO::fromJSON("./data.json")

# With `lapply()` we iterate over all items `x` in `jdata`
jdata_list <- lapply(jdata, function(x) {

  # For each `x`, we create a 1-dimensional list of variables we want to extract
  list(name = x$name,
       hq = x$headquarters,
       industry = x$industry[1],
       actions = names(x$actions)[1],
       support = x$actions[[1]][[1]]$country,
       measures = x$actions[[1]][[1]]$measures[1]
       )
  
})

# We bind the resulting list of lists into a data frame
df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, jdata_list))
```

Using [this example JSON](https://pastebin.com/raw/aTdctBfF), resulting in this data frame:
[image]

Comment: Thank you!!! V.much appreciate :')