# Ordering a dataframe by its subsegments

Tags: r, subset

My team and I are dealing with many thousands of URLs that have similar segments.
Some URLs have one segment ("seg", plural, "segs") in a position of interest to us.  Other similar URLs have a different seg in the position of interest to us.
We need to sort a dataframe consisting of URLs and associated unique segs 
in the position of interest, showing the frequency of those unique segs.

Here is a simplified example:

```
 url <- c(1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2)
 seg <- c("a", "c", "a", "d", "b", "c", "a", "x", "x", "y", "c", "b")
 df <- data.frame(url,seg)
```

We are looking for the following:

```
url freq seg 
 1   3    a   in other words, url #1 appears three times each with a seg = "a",
 2   2    b   in other words: url #2 appears twice each with a seg = "b",
 3   3    c   in other words: url #3 appears three times with a seg = "c", 
 3   2    x                                  two times with a seg = "x", and, 
 3   1    y                                  once with a seg = "y"
 4   1    d   etc.
```

I can get there using a loop and several small steps, but am convinced there is a more elegant way of doing this.  Here's my inelegant approach:

Create empty dataframe with num.unique rows and three columns (url, freq, seg)

```
 result <- data.frame(url=0, Freq=0, seg=0)
```

Determine the unique URLs

```
 unique.df.url <- unique(df$url)
```

Loop through the dataframe

```
 for (xx in unique.df.url) {
   url.seg <- df[which(df$url == unique.df.url[xx]), ] # create a dataframe for each of the unique urls and associated segs
   freq.df.url <- data.frame(table(url.seg))  # summarize the frequency distribution of the segs by url
   result <- rbind(result,freq.df.url)  # append a new data.frame onto the last one
 }
```

Eliminate rows in the dataframe where Frequency = 0

```
 result.freq <- result[which(result$Freq |0), ]
```

Sort the dataframe by URL

```
 result.order <- result.freq[order(result.freq$url), ]
```

This yields the desired results, but since it is so inelegant, I am concerned that once we move to scale, the time required will be prohibitive or at least a concern.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Also `reshape2::dcast(df, url + seg ~ "freq")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R you can do this :

```
aggregate(freq~seg+url,`$<-`(df,freq,1),sum)
# or aggregate(freq~seg+url, data.frame(df,freq=1),sum)

#   seg url freq
# 1   a   1    3
# 2   b   2    2
# 3   c   3    3
# 4   x   3    2
# 5   y   3    1
# 6   d   4    1
```

The trick with `$<-` is just to add a column `freq` of value 1 everywhere, without changing your source table.

Another possibility:

```
subset(as.data.frame(table(df[2:1])),Freq!=0)
#    seg url Freq
# 1    a   1    3
# 8    b   2    2
# 15   c   3    3
# 17   x   3    2
# 18   y   3    1
# 22   d   4    1
```

Here I use `[2:1]` to switch the order of columns so `table` orders the results in the required way.

Comment: I understand the second of your two answers, but there are several points about your first one that I do not understand.  I’ve looked up “aggregate” and think I understand it; the same with the use of the tilde, but the plus sign not so much (are you adding these vectors?  why?); can’t quite get how to interpret the use of all these together.  Finally, I simply cannot find any reference to ‘$<-‘.  Your comment below the solution suggests you’ve added a column of “freq” (distinct from my column of “Freq”), but what provides the actual frequency – the “sum”  after the comma?

Comment: `'$<-'(df,freq,1)` is returning what would be `df` after `df$freq <- 1`, so it's returning the same `df` with a `freq` column always equal to 1. then aggregate sums this variable, which is the same as counting rows, and store the result into the `freq` column of the output.

Comment: Here's a less smartass version : `df2 <-  df; df2$freq <- 1; aggregate(freq~seg+url, df2, sum)`

Comment: The plus sign is not to be seen as an addition operator, in this context it's used to enumerate the grouping variables, I'm summing `freq` by `seg` and `url`

Comment: I also can't find good documentation on operators such as `$<-`, `[<-`, `[[<-`. That could make a great post if it doesn't exist yet, I'll investigate. But in short in R when you're not making a "direct" assignment, like `a <- b`, but rather something like `a[2] <- b` or `a$x <- b` or `names(a) <- c("x","y")` you're actually calling respectively `a <- '[<-'(a,b,value=2)` , `a <- '[<-'(a,x,b)` and `a <- 'names<-'(a,c("x","y"))` under the hood. Understanding this open a lot of possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

An option can be to use `table` and `tidyr::gather` to get data in format needed by OP:

```
library(tidyverse)
table(df) %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
  filter(Freq > 0 ) %>%
  arrange(url, desc(Freq))


#   url seg  Freq
# 1   1   a     3
# 2   2   b     2
# 3   3   c     3
# 4   3   x     2
# 5   3   y     1
# 6   4   d     1
```

**OR**

```
df %>% group_by(url, seg) %>%
  summarise(freq = n()) %>%
  arrange(url, desc(freq))

# # A tibble: 6 x 3
# # Groups: url [4]
#    url seg      freq
#   <dbl> <fctr> <int>
# 1  1.00 a          3
# 2  2.00 b          2
# 3  3.00 c          3
# 4  3.00 x          2
# 5  3.00 y          1
# 6  4.00 d          1
```

Comment: I don't get your first solution, by gathering a single column you're only creating an additional column, which you remove at step 3.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Thanks for pointing out that. I have corrected it. I think that was left over when i misunderstood question and tried using   `gather` for processing. Your answer is impressive one as well.

Answer (score 0):

Would the following code be better for you?

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(url, seg) %>% summarise(n())
```

Comment: I've loaded by dplyr and magrittr (which comments in related questions cite), but I get an error for "group_by".  Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

```
url <- c(1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2)
seg <- c("a", "c", "a", "d", "b", "c", "a", "x", "x", "y", "c", "b")
df <- data.frame(url,seg)

library(dplyr)

df %>% count(url, seg) %>% arrange(url, desc(n))

# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#     url seg       n
#   <dbl> <fct> <int>
# 1     1 a         3
# 2     2 b         2
# 3     3 c         3
# 4     3 x         2
# 5     3 y         1
# 6     4 d         1
```

Comment: I've loaded by dplyr and magrittr (which comments in related questions cite), but I get 'Error in count(., url, seg) : could not find function "count" '.  Can you explain?

Comment: Try to use `dplyr::count(...)` instead. Or try to refresh your R session and load only `dplyr` package. Also check if you managed to load the package successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Or paste & tapply:

```
url <- c(1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2)
seg <- c("a", "c", "a", "d", "b", "c", "a", "x", "x", "y", "c", "b")
df <- data.frame(url,seg)

want <- tapply(url, INDEX = paste(url, seg, sep = "_"), length)
want <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(names(want), "_")), want)
colnames(want) <- c("url", "seg", "freq")
want <- want[order(want$url, -want$freq), ]
rownames(want) <- NULL # needed?
want <- want[ , c("url", "freq", "seg")] # needed?
want
```