# Create Function with special character R

Tags: r, function, character

I would like to create a function with the percentage sign in r. Something similar to the pipe operator in magrittr ($>$).

Here the code

```
%|%(x) <- function(x){...}
```

Unfortunately I received the following error:

```
Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "%|%"
```

Is there anything I am missing?
Thank you for your help

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27125672/what-does-function-mean-in-r/27129032#27129032

Answer (score 1):

[Syntactically invalid names need to be wrapped in backticks](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Quotes.html) (`` `…` ``) to be used in code. This includes operators when using them as regular R names rather than infix operators. This is the case when you want to define them:

```
`%|%` <- function(a, b) a + b
```

It’s also the case when you want to pass them into a higher-order function such as `sapply`:

```
sapply(1 : 5, `-`)
# [1] -1 -2 -3 -4 -5
```

(Of course this particular example is pretty useless since most operators are vectorised so you could just write `- (1 : 5)` instead of the above.)

You might also see code that uses quotes instead of backticks but this is discouraged.