# Reading Files from Web using R

Tags: r

I have been interested in studying R programming language recently and I came through this line of code which I am not understanding.

rugbyData <- rugbyHTMLData %>% html_nodes("table.wikitable") %>% .[[3]] %>% html_table

What does %>% means?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27125672/what-does-function-mean-in-r

Comment: have you tried to ask google already? https://seananderson.ca/2014/09/13/dplyr-intro/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R, %>% is the *pipe operator*.

It enables you to chain operations in a data pipeline, as the output of every step becomes the input of the next step.

Without it the code would look like this:

```
rugbyData <- rugbyHTMLData
extracted_nodes <- html_nodes(rugbyData, "table.wikitable")
selected_node <- extracted_nodes[[3]]
final_result <- html_table(selected_node)
```

...code that creates 3 useless variables

Note the "." that is a placeholder to say "the piped object goes here".

It's provide by the *magrittr* package →[Reference](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/)

NB: why magrittr ? → ["Ceci n'est pas une pipe / This is not a pipe"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Treachery_of_Images)

Comment: Thank you so much for the code. Can you please comment in each line so that I can understand what it does? Because I am still a beginner in R.

Comment: It is actually quite difficult given the lack of context, but here is what I can figure out:
if I'm correct you are using the `rvest` package to scrape a web page (I'm guessing a wikipedia page about Rugby, probably IRB rankings or World Cup winners) and extracting a table from there.. I can only suggest you to look the documentation of each function used here, particularly the inputs and outputs